# Continuous input as in wikipedia

Tags: ruby, input, web-scraping, wikipedia

So I am learning ruby and wanted to scrap from wikipedia.

```
require "rubygems"
require "json"
require 'restclient'
require 'crack'
require 'io/console'


parse = ""
5.times{
    inp = STDIN.getch
    parse += inp
    url="http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=#{parse}&namespace=0"

    data= Crack::JSON.parse(RestClient.get(url))
    puts data[1]
}
```

So this code i wrote takes input 5 times from the user concatenating the inputs and scraping the output from wiki search parsing the JSON. But i would like the input to be in a flow instead of the user hitting a character waiting for the output and hitting the next character again. Instead I want it to take input a couple of characters **without pressing enter** and if there is a pause say 1 sec or more it should start scraping and the giving the output.

A major reason behind is to allow user to erase some text he wrote or add more letters and the script to follow on whatever is left in the input field again **without never hitting enter** even after it has displayed the output after the initial pause.

Basically I want it to be just like in wiki itself. You can enter the search team modify it anytime and there is always a new output waiting.

**Edit:**

```
require "rubygems"
require "json"
require 'restclient'
require 'crack'
require 'io/console'

parse=""
ch=""
t2 =Thread.new do
    loop do
        temp=STDIN.getch
        parse+=temp
    end
end

t=Thread.new do
    loop do
        if parse!=ch
            sleep 1
            url="http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=#{parse}&namespace=0"
            data = Crack::JSON.parse(RestClient.get(url))
            #puts parse
            puts data[1]
            ch=parse
        end
    end
end

t.join
t2.join
```

This works perfectly but how do I end the threads when the user hits enter.

Comment: Why would you print data[1]?

Comment: @Sankalp data[0] is printing the first 'section' of the JSON and data[1] has the 2nd part and so on. Data[1] specifically has the names only so i printed data[1]

Comment: Use threads – the main thread processes user input (in a loop) and the "wiki" thread fetches the corresponding page.

Comment: @Stefan I used threads and got what i wanted. The only problem is that i cant figure out how to stop/kill the threads when the user hits enter. I sure can check if `temp=='\n'` but then how to end the threads if it is `true`. Please check the edit.

Comment: You only need one additional thread, not two. The input can be processed in your _main_ thread. Just `loop` until the user hits return (or escape or whatever), then `break` out of the loop and [`kill`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Thread.html#method-i-kill) the other thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getch` actually takes two (poorly documented) keyword arguments that do exactly what you want

```
# wait for 0 characters, timeout after 2 seconds
char = STDIN.getch min:0, time:2
```

If the user does not press any key within two seconds, `char` will be `nil`. You can call this in a loop and use that result as a trigger to start the scrape.

Comment: This definitely worked for the input part but pls check the edit. I used threads and it is more convenient. I just cant figure out how to exit the threads when the user hits  <kbd>Enter</kbd> i.e, when `temp=="\n"`

Comment: @Rishav just break out of the loops. If `temp` is a newline set some global `done=true` and then add `break if done` to your two loops.

Answer (score 0):

```
require "rubygems"
require "json"
require 'restclient'
require 'crack'
require 'io/console'

parse=""
ch=""
done=false
t2 =Thread.new do
    loop do
        temp=STDIN.getch
        if temp=="\n"
            done=true
            break
        end
        parse+=temp
    end
end

t=Thread.new do
    loop do
        if done==true
            break
        end
        if parse!=ch
            sleep 1
            url="http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=#{parse}&namespace=0"
            data = Crack::JSON.parse(RestClient.get(url))
            #puts parse
            puts data[1]
            ch=parse
        end
    end
end

t.join
t2.join

puts "Thanks!"
gets
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.chomp` and then it will not only read `\n` but spaces as well. Also only 1 thread is required, not 2.

```
require "json"
require 'restclient'
require 'crack'
require 'io/console'

parse=""
ch=""
done=false

t2 =Thread.new do
    loop do
        temp=STDIN.getch.chomp
        if temp==""
            done=true
            break
        end
        parse+=temp
    end
end

while !done
    if parse!=ch
        sleep 1
        url="http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=#{parse}&namespace=0"
        data = Crack::JSON.parse(RestClient.get(url))
        puts data[1]
        ch=parse
    end
end
t2.join
```